# Is there a way I can change the Build process if VS2013?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I hit the build, Run or Debug buttons in my ASP.Net VS2013 application I would like to change the events that happen. But I cannot find where these are defined.

Is there some place I can look to find out what these events are? Note that I do not want to add something before or after the build step. I want to see where the build steps are defined.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean when you say "events"? You mean project build order?

Comment: Can you be specific on what you are trying to achieve? Whatever it is you may have to play around with MSBuild Targets to achieve it. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx for details

Comment: I would like to remove the Microsoft components out of the build path and change these to NPM commands to mimify js etc and start up my own web server. I would also like to see where the current events are defined.

Comment: Also you can do it in post-build event in specific project settings and write custom scripts that will run npm on your project

Answer (score 0):

You can start by enabling verbose MSBUILD output.

Go to Tools->Options then find the Project and Solutions->Build and Run node, or you can type Ctrl-Q, type "build and run" and  hit enter.  Then, in that dialog change the build out verbosity to whatever level you want.

If you change it high enough, you can see every step of the build process in the output window.

Once you study that, that you can get a sense of what VS is doing.  You can see all the build targets, the order they're called in, how long they take, etc..

In that output, you can also see the MSBUILD targets files and their paths.  For instance:

> BuildInfoTargets = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\BuildInfo\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ReleaseManagement.BuildInfo.targets

However, editing these files is not a good idea.  You can override their functionality in your own MSBUILD targets, and there are hooks to call your own MSBUILD scripts.

I'd start with the "Getting Started" info, go from there:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/25/the-visual-studio-blog.aspx